# spresenseとパソコンのLTE通信

Tags: spresense, mqtt

SPRESENSEで取得した画像をパソコンに送りたいと思っています。
その際にWiFiは使用したくなく、LTEボードを使用しています。
SPRESENSEの公式のチュートリアルを参考に行ったところ
pc同士では通信ができたのですが、SPRESENSEとpc間では文字の通信すらできませんでした。
エラーなども出ていないため、どこが悪いかわかりません。
ご教授お願いします。

サブスクライバ側は以下のコマンドを実行しています。

```
mosquitto_sub -d -h broker.emqx.io -t spresense/mqtt
```

パブリッシャー側のコードは以下のものを使用しています。

```c
#include <LTE.h>
#include <ArduinoMqttClient.h>
// APN name
#define APP_LTE_APN "iijmio.jp" // replace your APN
/* APN authentication settings
 * Ignore these parameters when setting LTE_NET_AUTHTYPE_NONE.
 */
#define APP_LTE_USER_NAME "mio@iij"     // replace with your username
#define APP_LTE_PASSWORD  "iij" // replace with your password
// APN IP type
#define APP_LTE_IP_TYPE (LTE_NET_IPTYPE_V4V6) // IP : IPv4v6
// #define APP_LTE_IP_TYPE (LTE_NET_IPTYPE_V4) // IP : IPv4
// #define APP_LTE_IP_TYPE (LTE_NET_IPTYPE_V6) // IP : IPv6
// APN authentication type
#define APP_LTE_AUTH_TYPE (LTE_NET_AUTHTYPE_CHAP) // Authentication : CHAP
// #define APP_LTE_AUTH_TYPE (LTE_NET_AUTHTYPE_PAP) // Authentication : PAP
// #define APP_LTE_AUTH_TYPE (LTE_NET_AUTHTYPE_NONE) // Authentication : NONE
/* RAT to use
 * Refer to the cellular carriers information
 * to find out which RAT your SIM supports.
 * The RAT set on the modem can be checked with LTEModemVerification::getRAT().
 */
#define APP_LTE_RAT (LTE_NET_RAT_CATM) // RAT : LTE-M (LTE Cat-M1)
// #define APP_LTE_RAT (LTE_NET_RAT_NBIOT) // RAT : NB-IoT
// MQTT broker
#define BROKER_NAME "broker.emqx.io"   // replace with your broker
#define BROKER_PORT 1883                   // port 8883 is the default for MQTT over TLS.
                                           // for this client, if required by the server.
// MQTT topic
#define MQTT_TOPIC "spresense/mqtt"        // replace with your topic
// MQTT publish interval settings
#define PUBLISH_INTERVAL_SEC   1           // MQTT publish interval in sec
#define MAX_NUMBER_OF_PUBLISH  100          // Maximum number of publish
LTE lteAccess;
LTEClient client;
MqttClient mqttClient(client);
int numOfPubs = 0;
unsigned long lastPubSec = 0;
char broker[] = BROKER_NAME;
int port = BROKER_PORT;
char topic[]  = MQTT_TOPIC;
void doAttach()
{
  while (true) {
    /* Power on the modem and Enable the radio function. */
    if (lteAccess.begin() != LTE_SEARCHING) {
      Serial.println("Could not transition to LTE_SEARCHING.");
      Serial.println("Please check the status of the LTE board.");
      for (;;) {
        sleep(1);
      }
    }
    /* The connection process to the APN will start.
     * If the synchronous parameter is false,
     * the return value will be returned when the connection process is started.
     */
    if (lteAccess.attach(APP_LTE_RAT,
                         APP_LTE_APN,
                         APP_LTE_USER_NAME,
                         APP_LTE_PASSWORD,
                         APP_LTE_AUTH_TYPE,
                         APP_LTE_IP_TYPE,
                         false) == LTE_CONNECTING) {
      Serial.println("Attempting to connect to network.");
      break;
    }
    /* If the following logs occur frequently, one of the following might be a cause:
     * - APN settings are incorrect
     * - SIM is not inserted correctly
     * - If you have specified LTE_NET_RAT_NBIOT for APP_LTE_RAT,
     *   your LTE board may not support it.
     */
    Serial.println("An error has occurred. Shutdown and retry the network attach preparation process after 1 second.");
    lteAccess.shutdown();
    sleep(1);
  }
}
void setup()
{
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
      ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  Serial.println("Starting .");
  /* Connect LTE network */
  doAttach();
  int result;
  // Wait for the modem to connect to the LTE network.
  Serial.println("Waiting for successful attach.");
  LTEModemStatus modemStatus = lteAccess.getStatus();
  while(LTE_READY != modemStatus) {
    if (LTE_ERROR == modemStatus) {
      /* If the following logs occur frequently, one of the following might be a cause:
       * - Reject from LTE network
       */
      Serial.println("An error has occurred. Shutdown and retry the network attach process after 1 second.");
      lteAccess.shutdown();
      sleep(1);
      doAttach();
    }
    sleep(1);
    modemStatus = lteAccess.getStatus();
  }
  Serial.println("attach succeeded.");
  Serial.print("Attempting to connect to the MQTT broker: ");
  Serial.println(broker);
  if (!mqttClient.connect(broker, port)) {
    Serial.print("MQTT connection failed! Error code = ");
    Serial.println(mqttClient.connectError());
    // do nothing forevermore:
    for (;;)
      sleep(1);
  }
  Serial.println("You're connected to the MQTT broker!");
}
void loop()
{
  String testString = "test" + String(numOfPubs) + "!";
  unsigned long currentTime = lteAccess.getTime();
  if (currentTime >= lastPubSec + PUBLISH_INTERVAL_SEC) {
    // Publish to broker
    Serial.print("Sending message to topic: ");
    Serial.println(topic);
    Serial.print("Publish: ");
    Serial.println(testString);
    // send message, the Print interface can be used to set the message contents
    mqttClient.beginMessage(topic);
    mqttClient.print(testString);
    mqttClient.endMessage();
    lastPubSec = currentTime;
    numOfPubs++;
  }
  if (numOfPubs >= MAX_NUMBER_OF_PUBLISH) {
    Serial.println("Publish end");
    // do nothing forevermore:
    for (;;)
      sleep(1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

こんにちは。

提示されているコードを私のSpresense LTEボードで動作確認してみた結果、問題なく動作するようです。期待通り、Spresense LTEからPublishされた文字「test00!」がPC側で受信することができました。

実行した際のログがないので正しいことは言えませんが、以下の内容を確認してみると解決するかもしれません。

- 使用しているSIMカードのAPN情報が正しいかを確認する

  - 記載されているコードでは以下の情報になっています。

    - APN名 : iijmio.jp
    - ユーザ名 : mio@iij
    - パスワード : iij
- SIMカードが正しく挿入されているかを確認する

  - SIMカードの挿入方法は以下に画像付きで説明があります。
    [2.2.3.1. Spresense LTE拡張ボードへのSIMカード挿入方法](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/introduction_ja.html#_spresense_lte%E6%8B%A1%E5%BC%B5%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AEsim%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E6%8C%BF%E5%85%A5%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)

ご参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: 回答していただき、ありがとうございます。https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense　これを参考にしたのですが、tools/config.py examples/hello　pc上でこれを実行すると処理が終わらないです。どのサイトを参考に実行したかを教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: 質問文のコードはArduinoのスケッチだと思いますので、https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_set_up_ja.html こちらを参考にした方がよいと思います。本件とはまた別の質問でしたら、別の質問を新規に立てた方がわかりやすくてよいと思います。

Comment: 回答していただき有難うございます。参考にし、やってみます。